# How to compare two items of different types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not sure what the best way to do this is, but I would like to have two `enums` that I can compare. So when the one unit enters the trigger of the current unit that unit can detect whether or not the entering unit is attackable or not by comparing the two `enums`.

I know two different `enums` cannot be compared like in the example below, so what is the best approach when I don't what `None` to be an acceptable `unit type` but `None` can be an acceptable `attack type`?

```
public enum UnitType { Ground, Air, Water }
public enum AttackType { None, Ground, Air, Water }

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {
    public UnitType unitType;
    public AttackType attackType;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Unit unit = other.GetComponent<Unit>();
        if(unit.unitType == attackType) {
            // Send current unit to attack here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the enums are different types, and may have different integer values, you can still compare them by their symbol names, using `ToString()`. So instead of

```
if (unit.unitType == attackType)
```

just use

```
if (unit.unitType.ToString() == attackType.ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

## This fundamentally won't work this way.

You have two enums, which are backed by integers. The first one starts with `Ground` and the second one starts with `None`, this means that `UnitType.Ground == AttackType.None`, yikes!

What you should do is use a *single* enum:

```
public enum UnitType { None, Ground, Air, Water }
```

And fields:

```
public UnitType unitType;
public UnitType attackType;
```

`None` won't make sense for `unitType`, but that's OK! What's important is that these two fields have a *common relationship* with each other, and that relationship is what type of unit they *are* and what type of unit they can *attack.*

And we can go one step further:

```
[Flags]
public enum UnitType {
    None =   0,
    Ground = 1, // 1<<0
    Air =    2, // 1<<1
    Water =  4  // 1<<2
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
this.attackType = UnitType.Ground|UnitType.Air;
//...
if(unit.unitType & attackType > 0) {
    // Send current unit to attack here
}
```

Voila, no magic needed to make things that can attack more than one type! Or units that *are* more than one type! (Hovercraft that are `Ground` *and* `Water`)

Comment: How about also rename `UnitType` to `Nature`?

Comment: @vasily.sib Certainly an option. Not sure I agree with `Nature`, but something more generic works. (In my head "attacks Unit Type: Ground" reads pretty logically, as is "unit type is Unit Type: Ground", but I can see your point, just that `Nature` to me is more "green plant based").

Comment: While my initial though for this particular question was "Why not just use tags and gameObject.CompareTag()?", using Flags is a much more robust system. Which is ironic, because my screen is filled with exactly that, being how I implemented my server responses.

Comment: and one more suggestion: I think `unit.unitType.HasFlag(atackType)` is more readable, then `unit.unitType & attackType > 0`, but this is totally my opinion

Comment: @vasily.sib Looks like enums don't have that method in the C# version available in Unity. Also the value passed to HasFlag is an `AND` operation, but in this scenario we want `OR` (`unit.unitType & attackType > 0` checks Flying `OR` Ground, HasFlag checks `unit.unitType & attackType == attackType`, which is Flying `AND` Ground).

Comment: @Draco18s this method is exist in `mscorlib` since .net framework 4.0 (not sure if Unity works with this) and it actualy `OR` operation. `unit.unitType.HasFlag(atackType)` is exactly `(int)unit.unitType | (int)atackType > 0`. But I agree, that if you want "unit.unitType HAS ANY OF attackType" `unit.unitType & attackType > 0` make sense.

Comment: Unity has been on .NET 2.0 only until recently. There's an "experimental" 4.6 implementation, but I think the non-experimental is still like 3.5 or something. Anyway, from the docs. [The HasFlag method returns the result of the following Boolean expression: `thisInstance And flag = flag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I would take: set up a list of valid attacks and then simply compare against that list. Try this:

```
var validAttacks = new (UnitType, AttackType)[]
{
    (UnitType.Air, AttackType.Air),
    (UnitType.Air, AttackType.Ground),
    (UnitType.Ground, AttackType.Ground),
    (UnitType.Water, AttackType.Water),
    (UnitType.Water, AttackType.Air),
};
```

With this kind of list you can create any combination you like. You can even set it up at run-time to make it flexible.

Now, to use it, just do this:

```
var unit = UnitType.Water;
var attack = AttackType.Air;

var attackable = validAttacks.Contains((unit, attack));

Console.WriteLine(attackable);
```

This produces `True` because the combination of `UnitType.Water` and `AttackType.Air` is in the list.

---

Now, you could go one step further and set this kind of thing up:

```
public class Unit
{
    private Dictionary<(UnitType, AttackType), Action<Unit, Unit>> _validAttacks;

    public Unit()
    {
        _validAttacks = new Dictionary<(UnitType, AttackType), Action<Unit, Unit>>()
        {
            { (UnitType.Air, AttackType.Air), (s, o) => MissleAttack(s, o) },
            { (UnitType.Air, AttackType.Ground), (s, o) => MissleAttack(s, o) },
            { (UnitType.Ground, AttackType.Ground), (s, o) => TankAttack(s, o) },
            { (UnitType.Water, AttackType.Water), (s, o) => TorpedoAttack(s, o) },
            { (UnitType.Water, AttackType.Air), (s, o) => IcbmAttack(s, o) },
        };
    }

    public UnitType unitType;
    public AttackType attackType;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Unit unit = other.GetComponent<Unit>();
        if (_validAttacks.ContainsKey((unit.unitType, attackType)))
        {
            _validAttacks[(unit.unitType, attackType)].Invoke(this, unit);
        }
    }

    public void TankAttack(Unit self, Unit other) { ... }
    public void MissleAttack(Unit self, Unit other) { ... }
    public void TorpedoAttack(Unit self, Unit other) { ... }
    public void IcbmAttack(Unit self, Unit other) { ... }
}
```

Now I can incorporate an action associated with the pair of `(UnitType, AttackType)`. The code becomes quite concise and clear.

Comment: Sadly Unity's version of c# doesn't support tuples.

Comment: Not even with the `Tuple` type?

Comment: `Feature 'tuples' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 7.0 or greater.`